# Can I programatically get the LIKE count of different URLs?

Tags: facebook

is there any API available to get the like count for different urls..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by different URL's but you can get the like count of a URL with FQL via their link_stat table: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat.

Answer (score 3):

By making FQL query to 'link_stat',

To get from one URL, use this:

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = "site1.com"
```

To get from different URLs, use this:

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url in ("site1.com","site2.com")
```